# Django Bad Reqsut 400 issue

Tags: django

Had this Django Project that constant had this 400 issue but it miraculously solves itself.

6 months went and some setting change within the server and now the bad request had come back to haunt us.

I look up in this issue but every advice keeps saying the issue in 2 areas:

Within the Django `setting.py` first `DEBGU = Ture` second `ALLOW_HOST = [empty]`

I constantly relook over this fact to point I can even remember it in my sleep.

I would bag anyone who had knowledge of network, please share some possible solution.

Comment: Did you examine the logs? Does your code contains unit tests and integration tests? `ALLOWED_HOSTS` should be set to the host of your webapp.

Comment: First Thank you Gitnik (apologies late reply). Do my codes contain testing = no. My logs only print out the same 400 message issue

Comment: If this is an app in production, please disable DEBUG = True, and update your app with logs. Pinpoint which endpoint is giving you bad request (you should see that in your app), and add logs there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's actually spelled that way, you should change

```
DEBGU = Ture
```

to

```
DEBUG = True
```

Also, you can either set your ALLOWED_HOSTS to the host of your webserver/ip address, or just change it to:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS= ['*']
```

albeit its not recommended, and I would set it your IP address of whatever server you're running it from (if you're running it locally use "127.0.0.1". Please make sure its ALLOW**ED**_HOST**S** with an S and the ED, not just ALLOW_HOST. Proper spelling is important, otherwise your code will throw many errors!

Comment: first, thank you for your time. but I will say again I done several checks; spelling would be first on the agenda within checklist.